# How to duplicate my magento website keeping configuration to start another project?

Tags: magento-1.9, database, system-config

I have a magento website and I would like to start another project with distinct domain ,products and the appareance, keeeping all configuration.

I am using magento 1.9

Could your help me to achieve that ?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Import the **core_config_data** table from old database to new database.

Note: Make sure backup up this table first